# The plugin crisp could not be built due to the issue below the picture

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PNpP.png)

When i was build my application then i am faceing this issue.
i  was run: flutter build apk

Answer (score 0):

Please either post your `initState` for the crisp widget, or please a issue [Here](https://github.com/lunahq/flutter-crisp/issues) with the author.